# error class not found Slim subfolder

Tags: php, slim, production-environment

I'm putting my website on server but I have some issues to do so.
Indeed, I made it the simpliest way I know, I only copy-paste my files to my server.

I developed my website in php with Slim. It work perfectly locally, but not on the OVH server (mutualised Pro version).

It throw this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 
'App\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware' not found in 
/home/username/www/jobs/bootstrap/app.php:154 Stack trace: #0 
/home/username/www/jobs/public/index.php(9): require() #1 {main} thrown 
in /home/username/www/jobs/bootstrap/app.php on line 154
```

I'm not sure, but maybe it's because I placed it in a subfolder.

If somebody have a solution :)

Thank you in advance and sorry for the inconvenience, I'm nearly sure that it's due to a stupid mistake I made.

Comment: If you changed the location of ValidationErrorsMiddleware then you would absolutely have a problem, because the autoloader is searching for the file in app/middleware/.

Comment: I find my mistake, It was because of file name that change from uppercase to lowercase on the server. I don't know why. Thank you for your help Brian Gottier.

Comment: You didn't mention what your local/development environment is, but if it's Windows you should know that Linux (unlike Windows) is a case sensitive file system. Sometimes a dev working on Windows will have everything working fine, and then they upload to a *nix server and everything breaks. Anyways, glad you found your problem.